# How to make the listView row height change based on content?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, textview

I have the following layout which corresponds to a row in a list view. I wanted the TextView in the middle to expand based on the length of text. 
With the below layout, my textview is not even visible. Can someone point out what mistake I am doing?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/batman" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/display_name_color"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/favourite"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookmark"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/actions"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_info"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my adapter's getView function.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {


        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) { 

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, container, false);


            imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        } else { 
            imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        }

        imageView.setTag(position);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                mOnProfilePicClickCallback.onItemClick(position);
            }
        });
        //Load TextFields here
        Feed feed = (Feed) getItem(position);
        User user = null;
        if (feed != null) {
            user = (User) CommonData.users.get(feed.owner);
            TextView handle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.handle);
            TextView userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            TextView feedContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedcontent);

            handle.setText(feed.owner);
            if(tweeter!=null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(user.displayname))
            {
                userName.setText(user.displayname);
            }
            else
            {
                userName.setText(feed.owner);
            }
            feedContent.setText(feed.feedcontent);      
        }


        // Finally load the image asynchronously into the ImageView, this also takes care of
        // setting a placeholder image while the background thread runs
        if(user!=null)
        {
            mImageFetcher.loadImage(user.profileimageurl, imageView);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code in your listview adapter as well?

Comment: I have observed that when I set a fixed height to the listView row, the feedContent field is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

- Remove `android:layout_above="@+id/actions"`from your "content" TextView
- Add `android:layout_below="@+id/content"` to your "actions" LinearLayout
- Remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`from "actions"

It may work, if it still doesn't use LinearLayouts instead of RelativeLayout.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can you kindly explain why the ordering was important for RelativeLayout? I have faced such ordering issues before but it was no where documented.

Comment: I don't really like realtive layout so I use it only when I have to (Which is very rare). The problem was that you had 3 views - first one has alignParentTop, second one has "below the first but above the third" and the third one has "alignParentBottom". The result was that Relative layout actually skipped wrap content of second child and it worked like "match_parent". Everything wasn't wrapped but expanded as high as it could be and this is very wrong for a listView.

Answer (score 0):

In my ListView, every row height changes automaticly according the data.